Do the weak bosons and photon already exist in the electroweak epoch?
Do the W and Z bosons and also the photon already exist during the electroweak epoch? Or there are only the three W bosons and B boson?

The gauge group in some sense existed prior to the electroweak epoch. This is the basis for many Grand Unification Theories (GUT).  The electroweak epoch generally aligns with the seperation of the electroweak force from the color force and ends with the activation of the Higgs mechanism.  It is the effect of sponteous symmetry breaking which lead to the seperation of the electroweak force into the weak and electromagnetic forces.
During the electroweak epoch you see the creation of many of the higher energy weak bosons. The photon is part of the unified electroweak force, so existed. However, when symmetry was broken the photon remained massless while the other bosons became massive and decayed.
